# How do I track any changes of a single column in two dataframes - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DFs and I want to compare changes in values in DF1 and DF2. I know that I need to merge the two so that I have the Status columns lined up, but I'd also like to output only the ID's that had any changes in status.

DF1:

```
ID    Status 
1234  Cleared
5678  Validating
4321  Pending
8765  Cleared
9876  Blocked
6789  Blocked
```

DF2:

```
ID    Status 
1234  Blocked
5678  Validating
4321  Pending
8765  Cleared
9876  Validating
6789  Blocked
```

Output:

```
 ID    Status1   Status2
    1234  Cleared   Blocked
    9876  Blocked   Validating
```

Comment: Somehow, I've ever seen this question. Maybe dejavu :D

Answer (score 2):

Example data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Cleared', 'Validating', 'Pending', 'Cleared', 'Blocked', 'Blocked'], index = [1234, 5678, 4321, 8765, 9876, 6789], columns=['Status'])
df1.index.name = 'ID'

df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Blocked', 'Validating', 'Pending', 'Cleared', 'Validating', 'Blocked'], index = [1234, 5678, 4321, 8765, 9876, 6789], columns = ['Status'])
df2.index.name = 'ID'
```

Join `df1` and `df2` providing suffixes for the columns on the joined DataFrame

```
df = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2')
```

and then use boolean indexing

```
df[df.Status_1 != df.Status_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most effective way, but at least reach the goal. :)

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df3['Status_df2'] = df2.Status.copy()
df3 = df3.loc[df3.Status != df3.Status_df2]
```